# gMSA scheduled task cannot connect to S3 host

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3, gmsa

I've created a powershell script that collates specific files from all servers in a domain to a central management server, and then compresses and uploads to our cloud service providers S3 bucket (not Amazon).

It works as intended, however when trying to run the script as a scheduled task using a gMSA, it cannot connect to the remote server (The s3 endpoint), with a 'The remote name could not be resolved' error.

I think this may be related to the gMSA not being able to do the IE first start, or potentially having issues getting through the proxy (noting that I'm able to upload when I run the script), but I'm unsure. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/group-managed-service-accounts-overview#BKMK_SOFT

Comment: @jdweng I apologise if I am missing something obvious but I am not sure what I need to do here

Comment: The possible reason for failure is explained in the Software Requirement para.